# Regroup array to tree structure in PHP

Tags: php

I have an array like this one:

```
$array = array(
    array('id' => 'foo.bar'),
    array('id' => 'foo'),
    array('id' => 'foo.baz.bar'),
    array('id' => 'foo.bar.bar'),
);
```

I can `split` the `id` fields to get them as paths, and then I'd like to sort them into a tree... I tried this:

```
$result = array();

foreach($array as $element) {
    $path = explode('.', $element['id']);

    $subtree = $result;
    while(!empty($path)) {
        $path_element = array_shift($path);

        if(empty($path_element)) {
            $subtree['data'] = $element;
        } else {
            if(!is_array($subtree[$path_element])) {
                $subtree[$path_element] = array();
            }
            $subtree = $subtree[$path_element];
        }
    }
}
```

But all I get is a load of warnings and an empty `$res`-Array.

```
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: foo in tree.php on line 24
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() tree.php:0
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: bar in tree.php on line 24
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() tree.php:0
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: foo in tree.php on line 24
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() tree.php:0
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: foo in tree.php on line 24
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() tree.php:0
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: baz in tree.php on line 24
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() tree.php:0
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: bar in tree.php on line 24
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() tree.php:0
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: foo in tree.php on line 24
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() tree.php:0
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: bar in tree.php on line 24
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() tree.php:0
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: bar in tree.php on line 24
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() tree.php:0
```

(Line 24 is `$s = $s[$pe];`)

Any hint?

**EDIT**: My desired output would be like this

```
$res = array(
  'foo' => array(
    'data' => ...
    'bar' => array(
      'data' => ...
      'bar' => array(
        'data' => ...
      ),
    ),
    'baz' => array(
      'bar' => array(
        'data' => ...
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

The `data` elements are the original elements from the array.

Comment: Do you have an example how the tree must look like?

Comment: You aren't putting anything in $res, no wonder it's empty. Also, I'm not even sure what it's supposed to do.

Comment: @Benz Added an example.

Comment: @LambdaDusk I would first of all make your code readable. I mean, what do all those variables mean? '$p, $pe, $s, $res, $a, $e).. they don't really mean a lot.

Comment: Where is that 'data' key supposed to come from?

Comment: Note, that this way you wouldn't be able to create directories of name `data`

Comment: We'll, there are some answers, try it :D!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below generates the following result:

```
Array
(
    [foo] => Array
    (
        [data] => ...
        [baz] => Array
            (
                [bar] => Array
                    (
                        [data] => ...
                    )

        )

        [bar] => Array
        (
            [bar] => Array
            (
                [data] => ...
            )
        )
    )
)
```

I renamed some of you're variables...

```
$array = array(
    array('id' => 'foo.bar'),
    array('id' => 'foo'),
    array('id' => 'foo.baz.bar'),
    array('id' => 'foo.bar.bar'),
);


$res = array();

foreach($array as $e) {

    $parts = explode('.', $e['id']);

    $temp = &$res;

    foreach($parts as $key => $el) {
        if (!isset($temp[$el])) $temp[$el] = array();

        if ($key == count($parts)-1) $temp[$el] = array('data' =>  '...');
        $temp = &$temp[$el];
    }
}

print_r($res);
```

Answer (score 0):

Make $s referencing $res, using the `&`. This will pass the data by reference instead of by value.

```
$a = array(
    array('id' => 'foo.bar'),
    array('id' => 'foo'),
    array('id' => 'foo.baz.bar'),
    array('id' => 'foo.bar.bar'),
);

$res = array();

foreach($a as $e) {
    $p = explode('.', $e['id']);

    $s = &$res;
    while(!empty($p)) {
        $pe = array_shift($p);
        if(empty($p)) {
            $s['data'] = $e;
        } else {

            if(!isset($s[$pe])) {
                $s[$pe] = array();
            }
            $s = &$s[$pe];
        }
    }
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($res);
echo '</pre>';
```

results in

```
Array
(
    [foo] => Array
        (
            [data] => Array
                (
                    [id] => foo.bar
                )

            [baz] => Array
                (
                    [data] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => foo.baz.bar
                        )

                )

            [bar] => Array
                (
                    [data] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => foo.bar.bar
                        )

                )

        )

    [data] => Array
        (
            [id] => foo
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

Recursion is your answer.

and you would need something along the lines of:

```
<?php

$a = array(
    array('id' => 'foo.bar'),
    array('id' => 'foo'),
    array('id' => 'foo.baz.bar'),
    array('id' => 'foo.bar.bar'),
);

function createTree($path) {
    if ( count($path) === 1 ) {
        return array($path[0]=>array('data'=>'some random data here'));
    } else {
        $currentRoot = array_shift($path);
        return array($currentRoot => createTree($path));
    }
}

$result = array();

foreach ( $a as $item ) {
    $result = array_merge_recursive(
        $result,
        createTree(
            explode('.',$item['id'])
        )
    );
}

// $result now is what you wanted
```